# Is \@ necessary when capital letters are enclosed in a command?

Tags: spacing, capitalization

Normally, when a sentence ends in a capital letter, the space following the period is treated like a normal space. To get an end-of-sentence space, you must put `\@` before the period.

Is this also required if the capital letter is enclosed in a command, such as `\emph{}`, `\texttt{}`, or `\textbf{}`?

For example:

```latex
The pointer cannot be \texttt{NULL}. There is one exception:
```

vs.

```latex
The pointer cannot be \texttt{NULL}\@. There is one exception:
```

Comment: In this case yes, as you can see if you compare the two lines in your example (maybe more clearly in `The pointer cannot be \texttt{NULL}.\the\spacefactor There is one exception:`, where you can verify that the spacefactor is 1000 and not 3000 as you'd want after a period.) Of course it is easy to construct a command where it isn't needed (`\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{#1\@}` or `\newcommand*{\goo}[1]{#1 goo}`). Generally I'd expect the space factor to prevail unless the macro typesets additional text or explicitly changes the space factor.

Comment: The situation you're describing is not limited to all-caps letter groups being in the argument of some command; it also applies to all-caps letter groups being encased in `()` or `[]`. E.g., compare the outputs of `be (NULL). There is` vs. `be (NULL)\@. There is`, or the outputs of `be [NULL]. There is` vs. `be [NULL]\@. There is`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An image is worth many words.

[image]

The assignment of the space factor code is global, so whether or not you change fonts or use groups, after the last `L` the space factor code would be 999, meaning that the period would be interpreted as following an uppercase letter.

I set a very large `\xspaceskip` in order to emphasize the effect produced by the space factor after a period, which is 3000 if it was 1000 or more before it.

So `\@` is necessary.